# How to include the JWT for a Google Action endpoint?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Our architecture currently has all public access going through Kong. It validates all incoming requests contain a valid JWT. Is there a way to tell Google Action to include the JWT when configuring the webhook fulfillment?

Comment: Is it expecting the JWT as a header or via some other method? Does the JWT used have an expiration? Are you using Dialogflow or actions.json to configure your Action?

Comment: I think Kong can be configured to check a header field or a query parameter. Yes on expiration. Dialogflow.

Comment: I'm also wondering about this. The docs are not clear about this, but as far as I found out, the jwt is not included in dialogflow requests at all. Do you already have any solution, @kailoon?

Comment: Unfortunately, we had to work around it in our architecture.